# A function that wont stop/pause my script

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a `for` loop, inside the loop I check something with `if` and, when the conditions are met, I launch a function. The thing is this function includes a waiting period (`time.sleep`) and I noticed the loop is paused until that function is finished.

Is there any way to have my loop keep running while the function is executed?
I'm thinking maybe launch another script but I'm not even sure that wouldn't also pause the loop...

The goal is to be able to launch the function again before the first one is finished.

tho code kind of looks like this

```
def myfunction():
   time.sleep(30)
   print("waited 30 seconds...")
   do something
for something
   if condition:
      myfunction()
   print("the loop is resumed...")
```

Comment: Post the actual code not a description of it. Sounds like you want [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) though.

Comment: the code is secret, sorry

Comment: That's fine, we don't want the whole thing; create an anonymised [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried using threads? Why would invoking a new process block the current process?

Comment: I have no idea how to use threads. I was checking the option to have 2 scripts and import the second one as a module but it seems to me that it wouldn't make any difference as it would see the code of the second file just as if it were part of the first. no?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe can be fairly trivially solved with simple threading like so:

```
import time
import threading

def myfunction():
    time.sleep(30)
    print("waited 30 seconds.")
    # do whatever else

num = 0
mythreads = []
while(True):  # Just loop forever for demo purposes
    num += 1
    if num % 5 == 0:  # Execute the function once every 5 times
        newthread = threading.Thread(target=myfunction)
        mythreads.append(newthread)
        newthread.start()
    print("The loop is resumed.")
```

Comment: that looks good I will try it and see. Will the newt thread automatically stop once the function has been executed?

Comment: Looks like it's working as it should now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Seb if it's working for you, please accept the answer.